# How to create a conditional stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Can't seem to find one with a format close enough to get a solid answer. Trying to mess with select case statements, but it's proving to be a pain. I've got a basic payroll database I'm setting up (diagram shown below), and the idea is I want to do the following statement IF an employee's employee category (EmpCat) is 1, but a separate statement if it is 2 (basically hourly vs salary). Still fairly new to fiddling with T SQL, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've adjusted the procedure. It looks like it should do what I want now, and should even auto-sum the total hours worked in the pay period, but I'm now receiving an error stating that it is not contained in an aggregate function or a GROUP BY clause. Having trouble figuring out where this is an issue.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewTimesheet(
@LName varchar(50),
@FName varchar(50),
@ShiftType char(2),
@StartDate date,
@EndDate date,
@OTHours decimal(18,2),
@HolidayHours decimal(18,2)
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblTimesheet(
EmpID,
ShiftType, 
StartDate, 
EndDate, 
TotalHours, 
OTHours, 
HolidayHours,
NetPay
)
SELECT e.EmpID, @ShiftType, @StartDate, @EndDate, SUM(HoursWorked) , 
@OTHours, @HolidayHours, 
CASE WHEN ed.EmpCat = 1 
THEN (SUM(HoursWorked) * PayRate) 
ELSE (e.PayRate / 24) 
END
FROM tblEmployee e INNER JOIN tblEmployeeDetail ed ON e.EmpID = ed.EmpID 
inner join tblShifts on e.EmpID = tblShifts.EmpID
WHERE LName=@LName AND FName=@FName AND Date > @StartDate AND Date < 
@EndDate
GROUP BY e.EmpID, ed.EmpCat, e.PayRate, tblShifts.HoursWorked
END
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you limiting by name?  Would it not be better to do a batch run and do everyone in one go?

Comment: make two separate select statement and do the insert separately, 
select * from tblemployee a join tblemployeedetail b on a.empid = b.empid where b.empcat = 1

select * from tblemployee a join tblemployeedetail b on a.empid = b.empid where b.empcat = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one sp to deal with both you need to have the SELECT statement within the StoredProc looking something like:

```
SELECT e.EmpID, @ShiftType, @StartDate, @EndDate, @TotalHours, @OTHours, 
@HolidayHours, CASE WHEN ed.EmpCat = 1 THEN (@TotalHours * 
tblEmployee.PayRate) ELSE (insert logic for salary) END
FROM tblEmployee e INNER JOIN tblEmployeeDetail ed ON e.EmpID = ed.EmpID
WHERE LName=@LName AND FName=@FName
```

Otherwise if you want this only to deal with the hourly works, then you use:

```
SELECT e.EmpID, @ShiftType, @StartDate, @EndDate, @TotalHours, @OTHours, 
@HolidayHours, @TotalHours * tblEmployee.PayRate
FROM tblEmployee e INNER JOIN tblEmployeeDetail ed ON e.EmpID = ed.EmpID
WHERE LName=@LName AND FName=@FName AND ed.EmpCat = 1
```

HTH

Comment: This seems to do what I need it to - now I'm getting an error regarding it not being contained in either an aggregate function or a GROUP BY clause. The procedure as I have it is modified above.

Comment: You've added a SUM.  Every time you use any Aggregate function, you have to GROUP BY all the other fields in your SELECT statement.  In your case this is easy - just add GROUP BY e.EmpID at the very end of the SELECT statement

Comment: That's what I thought too - but when I add that it swaps the one error message for three more; stating that columns tblEmployeeDetail.EmpCat, tblEmployee.PayRate and tblEmployee.PayRate are invalid in the select list because they are not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - the compiler is quite right!  you need "GROUP BY e.EmpID, ed.EmpCat, e.PayRate, tblShifts.HoursWorked"  I had overlooked the fact that some of the items in your select list are a function of these values, and that is the same as selecting them direct.  My bad!

Comment: Bit late responding, but that did the trick. Thank you so much! Made my day *significantly* easier.

Comment: Shoot...one last thing (if you're still seeing these). It's successfully creating the time sheets now, but it makes separate insertions based on shift length - it inserts one for all the cumulative eight hour shifts, and one for all the 12 hour shifts.

Comment: Can you edit the question again to show the SQL you are now using?  I suspect this is because you have ShiftType in the SELECT and therefore GROUP on i, but it would be easier if I could see the latest version.

Comment: Sure, done now. Just added the GROUP BY clause and adjusted the criteria for salaried employees.

Oh, and removed the redundant user input variables - NetPay was calculated in the procedure, as was TotalHours. Fixed those

Comment: Ok I think I see your problem.  You can remove tblShifts.HoursWorked from the GROUP BY.  This is because in the SELECT part you now only use aggregate functions of HoursWorked, so it does not need to be in the GROUP BY